# Is there a quick way to export image from clipboard?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a hot key combination that will prompt "Save for Web & Devices.." interface for the clipboard content?

Answer (score 1):

No. For Save For Web to work, you must have document window. Save for web pulls the image data from the active document, and can't pull data from the clipboard.

However, you're probably aware, Photoshop stores most document data on the clipboard. So all you need to do is - New FIle, Paste, Enter Key, Save For Web, Save, Close. (Command-N, Command-P, Enter, Command-Option-Shift-S, Enter, Command-W, D)

Answer (score 0):

Alt + Shift + Ctrl + S you can also [customise your hotkeys](http://graphicssoft.about.com/cs/photoshop/qt/cscustomkeys.htm)

Comment: That didn't work. In case it is platform dependent, I am using OSX.

Comment: After a small research I've realized that you are simply referring to "Save for Web & Devices.." shortcut. That's not what the question is asking.